# which prop to use on v-tooltip to change its background color in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

By default the color of vuetify v-tooltip is dark gray. I want to give it a custom color (#E5E5E5). How can I change that?

Comment: see codepen: https://codepen.io/Luuk34/pen/PoQBdgM

Comment: there is no need for over writing css, this can be done using `color` prop on this component

Answer (score 0):

in vuetify v2 you can use `color` prop on this component.

[vuetify's tooltip color prop](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-color)

like this:

```html
<v-tooltip color="#E5E5E5">
...
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in vue3. It's not listed in the api doc https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-scrim

Comment: @matth thanks for pointing it out, I updated the link in the answer to refer to the vuetify's v2 doc